# Angular 2 AdminLte collapse box

Tags: angular, adminlte

I am trying to make a collapsible box in angular 2 using adminLTE bootstrap theme.
When I navigate between components and, then, click on the box to collapse, the script doesn't load. I suspect that some class is not loaded or something, and I think it's the 'box' class, but I'm not sure.

I tried to use this when I initialize the compoment:

Renderer2.addClass('document.body','box');

Then, it works, but when I collapse the box, all other boxes are collapsed too.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!